# Probability that modal value is mode of samples

Tags: probability

Forgive me, I'm sure this is easy; I haven't studied probability.

Say you take $n$ iid samples from a pmf with a unique modal value $x$ that has probability $p$. What is the probability that $x$ is the mode of the resulting set of $n$ outcomes?

Comment: What are these iid samples from a pmf?

Comment: Could you please provide an example? E.g. {0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.6} over the integers {1,2,3,4,5} 5 is the mode.

Comment: It depends on the distribution. Mode of the distribution carries almost no information.

Comment: This is not very simple. In practice, especially if the number of possible values of $X$ is large, I would do it by simulation.