# Probability of modal value being mode when rolling dice

Tags: probability

Suppose I roll two dice and sum the results, $n$ times. What is the probability that $7$ is the mode of the resulting set of $n$ values?

Comment: This is a specialization of my other question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839773/probability-that-modal-value-is-mode-of-samples, which got no answers.

Comment: You could do this by painful case-checking, perhaps on a computer. Eg. look at the probability you get a 7 and fit binomial to the splitting above and below the 7 of the other values. You'd then need to add in cases where you get a median of 7 from a 6 and an 8, for example.

Comment: It slightly depends on what you mean by *the* mode.  For $n=1$ the probability is clearly $\frac{1}{6}$.  For $n=2$ it is $\frac{1}{36}$ for being the unique mode but $\frac{11}{36}$ for being *a* mode. For larger $n$ I would use simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your linked question, I assume that you mean it to have a unique value for mode which is 7.

This is difficult since the probabilities are not uniform and we need the terms of the expansion $(p_2+p_3+p_4+\cdots+p_{12})^n$ where the degree of $p_7$ will be the highest in each term, and then substitute the probability values.

Here are some values if they are of anyone's interest, $n=6$ onwards are simulated values, which are much easier to obtain for higher $n$

\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline\\
n & P(n) \\
\hline\\
2 & \frac{1}{36} \\
3 & \frac{2}{27} \\
4 & \frac{229}{1944} \\
5 & \frac{104}{729} \\\\
6 & \approx 0.147 \\\\
7 & \approx 0.144 \\\\
8 & \approx 0.147 \\\\
9 & \approx 0.156 \\\\
10 & \approx 0.170\\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! As I said I've never studied probability, so I didn't know to think of polynomials, which is nice.

Comment: You are welcome! It's wonderful that you thought of such a tough problem even if you claim that you never studied probability!